# Is there a way Exclude an imported Package's Typings?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

## Summary

I have an npm dependency `@progress/kendo-ui` that includes the `typings`within the npm package, pointing to a separate index.d.ts file.  Unfortunately the typings are incorrect and produce compile time errors.  Kendo appear a bit slow in fixing this issue, so I'm trying to do a quick mitigation.  Using Typescript version `2.5.3`

## Question

Is there a way to exclude this specific module's typings?  In the tsconfig file I've tried a few things like typeAcquistion and exclude, but can't seem to figure it out

#### Tsconfig file

```json
"compilerOptions": {
        "module": "amd",
        "target": "es5",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "declaration": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "importHelpers": true,
        "paths": {
            "tslib": [
                "../node_modules/tslib/tslib.d.ts"
            ],
            "monaco": [
                "../node_modules/monaco-editor/monaco.d.ts"
            ]
        },
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node"
    },
```

and my attempted fixes

```json
"typeAcquisition": {
        "enable": true,
        "exclude": [
            "@progress/kendo-ui",
            "../node_modules/@progress/kendo-ui/index.d.ts",
            "../node_modules/@progress/kendo-ui",
            "node_modules/@progress/kendo-ui",
            "@progress",
            "kendo-ui"
        ]
    },
    "exclude": [
        "../node_modules/@progress/"
    ]
```

#### The error for reference:

```
E:/Repos/ExperimentationUI/node_modules/@progress/kendo-ui/index.d.ts(1201,15): error TS2430: Interface 'DataSourceTransportWithFunctionOperations' incorrectly extends interface 'DataSourceTransport'.
  Types of property 'create' are incompatible.
    Type '(options: DataSourceTransportOptions) => void' has no properties in common with type 'DataSourceTransportCreate'.
```

Comment: 1. I actually don't get the error, you might be working with a bit older version? you can either upgrade or say what version you are working with. You can sometimes extend type definitions and fix the error even if your locked on an older version.

2. Ugly hack: just add a pre-build task with what ever build tool you are using, to delete `node_modules/@progress/kendo-ui/index.d.ts`

Comment: Here's the full error:
`E:/Repos/ExperimentationUI/node_modules/@progress/kendo-ui/index.d.ts(1201,15): error TS2430: Interface 'DataSourceTransportWithFunctionOperations' incorrectly extends interface 'DataSourceTransport'.
  Types of property 'create' are incompatible.
    Type '(options: DataSourceTransportOptions) => void' has no properties in common with type 'DataSourceTransportCreate'.`

Tested with TS versions was 2.5.2 and 2.5.3

Comment: Im having a similar problem, I have `@types/react` installed (i need it for a second entry point, that is loaded into a WebView), but some types defined in `@types/react` clash with types i need in my main program. Tried excluding it in my main tsconfig without success.